# Reduce levels of nested dictionaries when they have one element

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, data-structures, nested

I need to reduce the nested levels of a dictionary when a node has 1 element, by appending the inner key to the upper key.

Example:

Given this dictionary:

```
{'A': {'a': {'1': {}}},
 'B': {'b': {'2': {}},
       'c': {'3': {'x': {}}},
       'd': {},
       'e': {'0': {},
             '1': {},
            },
       },
}
```

I need to return:

```
{'A a 1': {},
 'B': {'b 2': {},
       'c 3 x': {},
       'd': {},
       'e': {'0': {},
             '1': {},
            },
       },
 }
```

It should be generic for any number of levels, and the last element is always an empty dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first flatten the structure to retrieve all paths and then rebuild it using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
data = {'A': {'a': {'1': {}}}, 'B': {'b': {'2': {}}, 'c': {'3': {'x': {}}}, 'd': {}, 'e': {'0': {}, '1': {}}}}
def flatten(d, c = []):
  for a, b in d.items():
     if not b:
        yield (c+[a], b)
     else:
        yield from flatten(b, c +[a])

def compress(d):
   _d, r = collections.defaultdict(list), {}
   for [a, *b], c in d:
     _d[a].append((b, c))
   for a, b in _d.items():
      val = compress(b) if len(b) > 1 and all(j for j, _ in b) else b[0][-1]
      r[a if len(b) > 1 else a+' '+' '.join(b[0][0])] = val
   return r

print(compress(list(flatten(data))))
```

Output:

```
{'A a 1': {}, 
 'B': {'b 2': {}, 
       'c 3 x': {}, 
       'd ': {}, 
       'e': {'0 ': {}, 
             '1 ': {}}
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this recursive function works for your example:

```
def flatten_keys(key_so_far = '', d={}):
    if len(d) > 1:
        sub_dict = {}
        for (k,v) in d.items():
            sub_dict.update(flatten_keys(k, v))
        return {key_so_far: sub_dict} if key_so_far else sub_dict
    elif d == {}:
        return {key_so_far: {}}
    else:
        k,v = list(d.items())[0]
        key_so_far += (' ' if key_so_far else '') + k
        return(flatten_keys(key_so_far, v))

input_d = {'A': {'a': {'1': {}}},
 'B': {'b': {'2': {}},
       'c': {'3': {'x': {}}},
       'd': {},
       'e': {'0': {},
             '1': {},
            },
       },
}

flatten_keys(input_d)

# {'A a 1': {}, 'B': {'b 2': {}, 'c 3 x': {}, 'd': {}, 'e': {'0': {}, '1': {}}}}
```